Alternate rows using multiple columns and specific order in R
I have a data.frame with more or less the following structure:
structure(list(user = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"), group = c("G2", 
"G2", "G2", "G2", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G1", "G2", "G1", 
"G1", "G2", "G1", "G2"), gender = c("M", "H", "H", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "H", "H", "M", "H"), level = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

What I want to do is:

Arrange group so that all observations from G1 appears first
Within groups, alternate gender by "M", "H", "M", "H", etc and level by 1, 2, 3, 4

so that my data could like this: (This image is for illustrative purposes only)

I tried with
db%>%
    arrange(group, gender, level) 

and also with
db %>% 
    arrange(factor(group, levels = c("G1", "G2")),
        factor(gender, levels= c("M", "H")),
        factor(level, levels= c(1, 2, 3, 4)))

but none of these give me what I try to achieve.
Any advice will be much apppreciated.

You have 6 G1 rows in db, but your proposed output only has 4. What is the desired order for the other 2?

Looking at this further, I can't make sense of it at all. There is only one group == 'G1' & gender=='H' row in the example but multiple in the output. Either the example data needs to be more representative, or this is going to require more than just a sort to get the desired output.

I know what you mean. There's no perfect match for the pairs H, M and levels 1, 2, 3, 4 but I want a db which can be as closest as is possible to the desired output.

You don't define what "closest as is possible" means when the output is different than the input, so this question doesn't seem answerable.

If you order by level 1,2,3 etc, there's no way to then reorder by gender and not shuffle the previous order.

@AndreWildberg Yeah, it looks like this kind of arrangement is not possible. I can't find neither here nor somewhere else something that could guide me. Maybe I should delete this question.

To sort the data in alternating values of gender ("M" then "H") within group, you can use the following code:
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, idx=row_number(), 
      .by=c(group, factor(gender, levels=c("M", "H"))) |>
  arrange(group, idx, gender) |>
  select(-idx)


# A tibble: 16 × 4
   user  group gender level
   <chr> <chr> <chr  <int>
 1 5     G1    M          1
 2 13    G1    H          1
 3 6     G1    M          2
 4 10    G1    M          2
 5 12    G1    M          4
 6 15    G1    M          3
 7 1     G2    M          1
 8 2     G2    H          2
 9 4     G2    M          4
10 3     G2    H          3
11 7     G2    M          3
12 14    G2    H          2
13 8     G2    M          4
14 16    G2    H          4
15 9     G2    M          1
16 11    G2    M          3


There is no easy way to do that.
Despite that, it could show lights the following approach:
attach(df)
a <- which(group == "G1" & gender == "H")
b <- which(group == "G1" & gender == "M")
c <- which(group == "G2" & gender == "H")
d <- which(group == "G2" & gender == "M")

# Filling with NAs till each group reach same length
a <- c(a, rep(NA, length(b)-length(a)))
c <- c(c, rep(NA, length(d)-length(c)))

# To interlace groups
e <- na.omit(c(rbind(a,b)))
f <- na.omit(c(rbind(c,d)))

o <- c(e,f) # final ordering

OUTPUT
df[o,]
   user group gender level
13   13    G1      H     1
5     5    G1      M     1
6     6    G1      M     2
10   10    G1      M     2
12   12    G1      M     4
15   15    G1      M     3
2     2    G2      H     2
1     1    G2      M     1
3     3    G2      H     3
4     4    G2      M     4
14   14    G2      H     2
7     7    G2      M     3
16   16    G2      H     4
8     8    G2      M     4
9     9    G2      M     1
11   11    G2      M     3

